# Exposing multiple ports in deployment in Kubernetes

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, amazon-eks, amazon-ecr, kubernetes-deployment

Hi I am currently trying to set up an application using Amazon EKS.
I have an application that uses two ports 2237 and 2238.

When I run it on a local machine using the following command on a local machine both ports seems to be working fine.

```
docker run -p 2237:2237 -p 2238:2238
```

I have pushed the image to Amazon ECR and am currently trying to create pods using deployment.

The yaml file that I used to create the pods are as follows.

```yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: evcloud-vertx
  namespace: evcloud
spec:
  replicas: 2
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: evcloud-tcp
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: evcloud-tcp
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: evcloud-tcp
          image: ecr directory
          ports:
            - containerPort: 2238
            - containerPort: 2237
```

The result seems to be "Error" for one and "CrashLoopBackOff" for the other.

My guess is that something went wrong when exposing the two ports, and it would be appreciated if anyone could give me some feedback on this.
[image]

I am really new to both AWS and Kubernetes, so help of any sort would be sincerely appreciated.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: That is the correct way to expose a port. What does the pod log say?

Comment: I tried getting the logs using the following command "kubectl --namespace evcloud logs evcloud-vertx-dff755677-wrlc7" but seems to get "standard_init_linux.go:228: exec user process caused: exec format error" so I am guessing that there was a problem when running my docker file. Thank you for your feedback

Answer (score 0):

This seems to have been a problem with the arm architecture.
I am currently using an m1 Mac and the issue was resolved after specifying the platform when creating docker image